# Matlab code to identify the maximum peak (coordinate) of a polynomial curve

Tags: matlab, max, coordinates, polynomials

I have this set of `x` and `y` data that would fit into a polynomial curve. Is there any way using Matlab (or Excel) to graph this data, trace a polynomial fit to it,  and identify the (x,y) coordinate for the maximum peak of the curve; not the maximum point out of the ones I inserted, but the highest point of the curve itself.

I found this code that plots the data and marks the maximum and minimum points, but it plots the max and min out of the ones I inserted, not the peaks of the curve itself. Also, it doesn't trace a polynomial fit.

```
x = [53, 62, 69, 71, 78, 89, 99, 106, 118, 133, 140, 151, 157, 164];
y = [211, 227, 233, 245, 262, 278, 283, 289, 282, 276, 268, 259, 252, 246];

idxmin = find(y == max(y));
idxmax = find(y == min(y));
plot(x,y,'-p','MarkerIndices',[idxmin idxmax],...
    'MarkerFaceColor','red',...
    'MarkerSize',15)
```

This is the plot that I'm getting:

[image: Figure showing data with minimum and maximum annotated.]

What I want to know is the exact coordinate of the highest peak of the polynomial fit.

Comment: Have you looked at `polyfit` from the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html)?  Once you have the polynomial approximation, there are multiple ways to get the peak. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15583989/8239061).  Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30075007/8239061) might be of interest.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan, thank you so much. I was able to trace the polynomial trendline, but I still can't figure out how to identify the maximum of the polyfit curve.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with your updated code?  Would make it much easier to see best way to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

This solution assumes a quadratic fit (though this could be changed) and avoids using `polyfit` just to show alternative approach.  Not claiming this is better than other methods.

**1. Fit polynomial**
(*a*) This approach uses `fminsearch` to quickly get a numerical fit.  Note that this requires finding a reasonable starting point for the polynomial coefficients, `c0`.

```
% MATLAB R2017a
x = [53, 62, 69, 71, 78, 89, 99, 106, 118, 133, 140, 151, 157, 164];
y = [211, 227, 233, 245, 262, 278, 283, 289, 282, 276, 268, 259, 252, 246];


fh=@(c) c(1) + c(2)*((x-c(3)).^2);      % to pass to fminsearch
errh=@(c) sum((fh(c)-y).^2);            % uses Least Sum of Squared Error
% err2h=@(c) sum(abs(fh(c)-y));         % sum of absolute error

qh=@(X,c) c(1) + c(2)*((X-c(3)).^2);    % for plotting 


c0 = [300 -0.07 100];                   % initial guess at coefficients
[c, SSE] = fminsearch(errh,[300 -0.1 100])
```

(*b*) Other methods available for this step include using `polyfit` ([see here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/polynomial-curve-fitting.html)). Other [methods](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html) also options.

**2. Finding the maximum ordinate**
(*a*) Use basic calculus to find maxima. If you know the form of the polynomial, the take 1st derivative (dy/dx) & set equal to zero. Solve for x. If 2nd derivative, if negative, you have the a local maximum. This can be achieved analytically.

(*b*) Numerically find this coordinate to some tolerance.

```
xstep = 0.01;
Xrng = min(x)-10:.01:max(x)+10;

figure, hold on
plot(x,y,'ko')
xlim([0 180])
ylim([0 300])
plot(Xrng,ones(size(Xrng))*c(1),'r-')
plot(Xrng,qh(Xrng,c),'b--')

[y_max,ind] = max(qh(Xrng,c));
x_max = Xrng(ind);
disp(['Maximum occurs at (' num2str(x_max) ', ' num2str(y_max) ')'])
```

> Maximum occurs at (115.75, 285.4542)

[image: Plot showing data, fitted polynomial (quadratic), and maximum]

(*c*) You can also use `findpeaks` from the Signal Processing Toolbox.

```
[y_max,locs] = findpeaks(qh(Xrng,c))
x_max = Xrng(locs)
```

**Extensions:**
Though not shown, it is possible to (1) force maximum of the fitted polynomial to be the same as maximum from data (either as the y-value or as the (x,y) coordinate), or (2) weight which parts of the data you want a tighter fit to.